# Clarify the status of the cashew

Tags: kde

There are lots of references to the "cashew" in KDE documentation.  In what version of KDE did it disappear?  And what replaces it?

Comment: Possibly relevant https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/kde-kills-desktop-toolbox-icon